# Convertir código c en lenguaje c++

Tags: c++, c

Se podría pasar este código diseñado en c a c++, o que es lo que se tiene que cambiar?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main() 
{
    int x[10];
    int i,j,a;
    int max;
    int min;
    int prom,suma;
    // Capturando los valores del arreglo
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Capture valor estatura: [%d]: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    }

    /* Ordenando el arreglo */ 
    for (i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
    for (j=0; j <10; j=j+1) 
    if ( x[i] < x[j] ) 
    { 
    a= x[i]; 
    x[i]=x[j]; 
    x[j]=a;
    }

    // Buscar mínimo, máximo, y calcular suma
    min = x[0];
    max = x[0];
    suma = x[0];
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(x[i] > max)
        {
            max = x[i];
        }
        else if(x[i] < min)
        {
            min = x[i];
        }
        suma += x[i];
    }
    // Calcular promedio
    prom = suma/10;



    printf("\n");
    printf("Estatura maxima es: %d  Estatura minima es: %d \n", max, min);


    /* Desplegando el contenido del archivo */ 
    for(i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
    printf("%d ", x[i]);

    printf("\nPromedio estaturas: %d\n", prom);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ es un superconjunto de C. Esto quiere decir que un programa C correcto compilará también bajo un compilador de C++. En tu caso acabo de comprobar que así es (aunque tuve que quitar `<conio.h>` y el `getch()` final para poder compilar en un Unix). Otra cosa sería rediseñar el programa para que use características propias exclusivas de C++, como por ejemplo que maneje la entrada/salida con `cin`/`cout`, o programación orientada a objetos.

Comment: @abulafia, como he comentado en la respuesta de PedroHernandez, C++ ya no es un superconjunto de C, son dos lenguajes independientes y cada uno tiene características que no existen en el otro lenguaje... tienen mucho en común pero ya hace 7 años que son disjuntos

Answer (score 1):

Cualquier codigo c compila en c++, si lo que quieres decir es que le cambiarías para usar cosas únicas de c++, pues puede ser la entrada y salida estandar

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

Asi ya puedes usar cout y cin para salida y entrada respectivamente, es decir en vez de poner

```
printf("Capture valor estatura: [%d]: ", i+1);
scanf("%d",&x[i]);
```

Usas

```
cout<<"Capture valor estatura ["<<i+1<<"]: "<<endl;
cin>>x[i];
```

Comment: El primer párrafo de esta respuesta no es del todo cierto. Cositas tontas de C11 como `noreturn` o las macros genéricas no están soportadas en C++. Bueno, realmente `noreturn` sí está soportado pero con una sintaxis diferente (a partir de C++11, va con dos llaves `[[ noreturn ]]` y su posición varía entre ambos lenguajes), por lo que su uso no es portable de C  a C++

Answer (score 0):

¡Claro que se puede!

Primero veamos las diferencias: eliminaremos `#include <conio.h>` junto con `getch();` porque no es un estándar de c++ y aqui no lo necesitas. Cambiamos `#include <stdio.h>` por la estándar de c++ `#include <iostream>`, para que los flujos de entrada y salida de esta librería funcionen se hace uso del siguiente espacio de nombre  `using namespace std;`.

Se ha reemplazado el flujo de salida de `printf` por `cout`. También el flujo de salida `scanf` por `cin`.

El salto de linea que lo hacías con `\n` lo haces con `endl`.

A continuación te dejo el código con el cambio hecho.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int x[10];
    int i,j,a;
    int max;
    int min;
    int prom,suma;
    // Capturando los valores del arreglo
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << "Capture valor estatura: [" << i+1 << "]: ";
        cin >> x[i];
    }

    /* Ordenando el arreglo */ 
    for (i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
    for (j=0; j <10; j=j+1) 
    if ( x[i] < x[j] ) 
    { 
    a= x[i]; 
    x[i]=x[j]; 
    x[j]=a;
    }

    // Buscar mínimo, máximo, y calcular suma
    min = x[0];
    max = x[0];
    suma = x[0];
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(x[i] > max)
        {
            max = x[i];
        }
        else if(x[i] < min)
        {
            min = x[i];
        }
        suma += x[i];
    }
    // Calcular promedio
    prom = suma/10;


    cout << endl << "Estatura maxima es: " << max << "  Estatura minima es: " << min << endl;


    /* Desplegando el contenido del archivo */ 
    for(i=0; i <10; i=i+1) 
        cout << x[i] << " ";

    cout << endl <<"Promedio estaturas: "<< prom << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: podrías explicar los cambios que haz hecho dentro del código?

Comment: Tengo un blog en donde subo mis programas hechos en c y c++ que me dejan de tarea. Por favor visítalo http://consolaweb.com/

Comment: Hice los  cambios.